# small Google maps marker with dynamic text

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-custom-view

[image]

How do I add one of these small markers with dynamic text, like seen in the image?

Can this be done easily or do I have to generate bitmaps on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would say it can be done easily... 
Here is some code which I use in my app, maybe it will give you an idea:

```
 BitmapDescriptor customBitmap;

 customBitmap = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);

 if (mMap.getMapType() != GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            customBitmap = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                     .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_alt);
 }
```

Edit: sorry, I misunderstood... I recognize you want to provide the text on the map. Sorry I don't know, but I guess this text is presented by the Google Map itself...
But maybe the result will be the same when you're using a bitmap which shows only text..

Comment: It's a clickable marker+text that "Google" adds somehow. I guess I could generate bitmaps with icon+text+transparent background to achieve this. Just have the feeling there must be a better way..

Comment: Maybe you'll find this useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay